# Building v8 on Mac with a 'missing Makefile-x64' error

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4, osx-lion, v8

What references do you know of related to problems with installing and building v8 on Mac and overcoming an error with message something like "missing Makefile-x64"?

Longer version:
I am now over 24 hours in to my attempt at using PyV8 in a python script on OSX. Describing each problem and attempts to fix it would take too long. I suspect the real problem is that up until yesterday *I was a Windows user*, and my experience installing PyV8 for use in a Python application was painless. But on OS X PyV8 just won't install because v8 was missing, so I install v8 using brew, which still didn't install the ".h" files that PyV8 seemed to want to reference, so I download the v8 source and attempt building it but after solving a dozen other minor issues I just can't seem to get past an error about a Makefile-x64 missing file when I call make native in the v8 source folder. So...

What references do you know of related to this problem?

Related question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44858/how-to-install-xcode-form-downloaded-package

Comment: Hey dave, what command did you use to build v8?

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo Hey! I downloaded the source form git, then set some GYP system variables that the v8 guide talks about, then ran make dependencies just fine. My next step caused the error: make (I also tried variations causing similar 'missing' errors: make native, make x64)

Comment: Is this the guide that you're following: http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/wiki/HowToBuild? I'm not sure which step are you on. Did you try pre build binary for OS X in here: http://www.dcl.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/home/loewis/pyv8/ It's a bit old but I think it should work.